# How can I hard link a file in a jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My overall objective is, sync a file from S3, and then hard link it to avoid "many copies" and have space savings while building docker containers. Here's what I have so far

```
withAWS(region: 'us-east-1') {
    s3Download(
        bucket: 'artifacts.mydomain.tld',
        file: "${env.ORACLE_RPM}",
        path: "${env.HOME}/${env.ORACLE_RPM}",
    )
    script {
        linkBlocking("etc/docker/${env.PROJECT}/${env.ORACLE_RPM}", "${env.HOME}/${env.ORACLE_RPM}")
    }
}
```

the `s3Download` works, though I'm unsure if it would update the file if a newer version was available.

However when I've tried to use the [`FileSystem`](http://vertx.io/docs/groovydoc/io/vertx/groovy/core/file/FileSystem.html#FileSystem(java.lang.Object)) class, I can't actually figure out the right calling convention, the constructor at the least seems underdocumented.

Comment: what's `linkBlocking()`?

Comment: @StephenKing I linked the FileSystem class in the original post, it's in that class

Comment: Ah, I see.. this is a function from that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't figured out how to do this in groovy, I got a sandbox error when I tried to use Java's nio `Files`, but doing it with the shell step works

```
           withAWS(region: 'us-east-1') {
                script {
                    try {
                        s3Download(
                            bucket: 'artifacts.mydomain.tld',
                            file: "${env.HOME}/${env.ORACLE_RPM}",
                            path: "${env.ORACLE_RPM}",
                        )
                    }
                    catch (Exception e ) {// don't update the file if it exists
                    }
                    finally {
                        sh "ln -f ${env.HOME}/${env.ORACLE_RPM} etc/docker/${env.PROJECT}/${env.ORACLE_RPM}"
                    }
                }

            }
```